# python запись в Excel в цикле с новой строки

Tags: python, строки, xlsx

Есть построчный список `ips.txt` c ip add
При выполнении цикла, необходимо записывать host в таблицу xlsx в новой строке +1
Мой код переписывает каждым следующим одну и ту же ячейку

- в операторе if также потребуется записать значение в новой строке и уже другом столбце
  Пробовал другую библиотеку openpyxl, как-то тоже не срослось

```
host = open('ips.txt')
for host in hosts:
    LLDP = subprocess.Popen(['snmpwalk -c public -v2c ' + host.strip() + ' .1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = LLDP.communicate()
    LLDP_OUT = str(out, 'utf-8')
    print(LLDP_OUT)
    row = 1 
    column = 0 
    worksheet.write(row, column, host)
    row += 1
    if re.search('4.1.1.10.\d{0,8}.17474.\d = STRING: "Fiber', LLDP_OUT):
        row = 1
        column = 1
        worksheet.write(row, column, 'Neighbor Fiber')
        print('xg1/1/1 neighbor Fiber')
    else:
        print('xg1/1/1 another neighbor or no link')
```

Как то так я хочу получить вывод:
[image: Ожидание]
Спасибо!

Comment: row не пробовали увеличивать на единицу после записи?

Comment: `row = 1` лучше бы поставить перед циклом

Comment: row увеличивал на ед...не помогало...поставил row перед циклом, помогло...пока тестирую...спасибо